# Working with Selenium and multiple Chrome Browsers on Linux

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have developed a python application for Selenium using Chrome/ChromeDriver.
The application seems to work pretty well on my Windows Based Laptop, but when I move everything to my Linux Based Server Machine, I started to notice strange behaviors when running multiple Browser instances in parallel.

The approach I am currently using is pretty simple: I have one Daemon, launching a separated process instance with Popen for each sub process, as follows:

```
            sub_call = subprocess.Popen(["python", "my_script.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

Ideally each sub process should run in parallel in a separated Chrome session, with its own Browser parameters (cookies, proxies, etc...).
No sync mechanisms are implemented among any sub process.

For now I would prefer to avoid Selenium Grid because I only plan to run few instances in parallel (let's say less than 5), and I have hardware constraints being everything running in a Docker on a NAS.

This is the code I use to instantiate every ChromeDriver object:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent={}'.format(constants.BROWSER_AGENT_HEADER))
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port={}".format(CHROME_DRIVER_DEBUG_PORT))
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size={}".format(CHROME_DRIVER_RESOLUTION))
if ON_POSIX:
   chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
   # chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-address={}'.format(CHROME_DRIVER_DOCKER_BIND))
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://{}:{}'.format(self.proxy_ip, self.proxy_port))

cap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

cap['proxy'] = {
            "httpProxy": proxy_address_str,
            "httpsProxy": proxy_address_str,
            "ftpProxy": proxy_address_str,
            "sslProxy": proxy_address_str,
            "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        }

cap['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}

service_args = ["--log-path={}/chromedriver.log".format(LOGFILE_PATH),
                        "--whitelisted-ips=",  "--profile-directory={}".format(username)]

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=constants.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH,
                               service_args=service_args, desired_capabilities=cap, options=chrome_options)
```

Where I tried to separate each user environment with the --profile-directory arg (NOTE: I just put my system user_names, without setting up any Chrome profile actually)

However it seems that while under windows each process opens its own Chrome window, on Linux there are conficts.
The major issue I had is that when a process ends, if it executes just one of the above lines, effects the other's processes browser in some ways:

```
driver.quit()
driver.close()
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

I have temporary commented each of the above lines. It seems to work perfectly (10 hours running at normal duty, no issues)

Now my concern is that I want to avoid that all the open instances of Chrome will end up to get all my memory.

How can I clean the browser without effecting my other running processes?

Thank you in advance for any support I will receive.

Comment: show code that sets CHROME_DRIVER_DEBUG_PORT (and your multi-threading)

Comment: thank you @pcalkins , I just added the requested details. Note that I have: 1) added the service_args as reported above; 2) removed from the debug port to avoid any binding interferences (it doesn't work anyway since it gives me a blank page when I click to the page link that usually appears inside the main debug page, but this is another story, and I am considering to cover it with a dedicated post). Still having issues. :(

Comment: you shouldn't need to set the profile dir.  It'll create a new temporary profile for each thread.  You still haven't shown how you are passing in vars... but the fact that it works on one OS and not the other sort of points to path issues.

Comment: @pcalkins can you share more details, please? --log-path works correctly (each process has its dedicated log), CHROME_DRIVER_PATH is a constant. All the paths to Selenium/Chromedriver/Chrome are constants. I am assuming that if they works for one process, than they will for any process pool size.

Comment: @pcalkins For what regards the profile dir, it is a mere test to enforce insulation between each running process and its associated users. (This is a relevant requirement of my code, the more each process is separated the better it is). Users are recycled, but setting up each profile manually would be too expensive (I am working with a sample of 100 users). Are there better options?

Comment: yes, just don't set it. (the profile dir option in the driver)  The driver will automatically create a temp folder for each.

Comment: Ok, done. In the meanwhile I figured out half of the problem, as above explained :)

Comment: driver.quit() would be the proper way... it should close the browser and dispose of the webdriver.    Unfortunately there can be issues if during the disposal another driver is launched.  I've never really narrowed this down, but I think it happens when browser cleanup isn't complete and a new browser session is launched.  (It can then sometimes use the cleaning up process' dev port?  Again I've never figured out the exact issue there.)